# Display specific "categories" from pList

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am creating a simple quiz app. I already have a pList file where all of my questions are stored and have put in "Category" key for each question.
My pList structure is like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Questions</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Answers</key>
        <array>
            <string>(Answer Choice 1)</string>
            <string>(Answer Choice 2)</string>
            <string>(Answer Choice 3)</string>
            <string>(Answer Choice 4)</string>
        </array>
        <key>Category</key>
        <string>(Category Here)</string>
        <key>CorrectAnswer</key>
        <string>(Correct Answer Here)</string>
        <key>Question</key>
        <string>(Question Here)</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I can successfully display the contents of the pList file in Quiz mode.

However, I wanted to give the users the option to CHOOSE or SELECT which CATEGORY/s they would like to be tested on. With that in mind, I am planning to create a "Settings" view consisting of CHECKBOXES where the user will be able to select one or more category/s of their liking.

My question is this, what code should I use to be able to display ONLY the "Question arrays" which have the "Category" that the user has selected?
And how do I connect that code to the checkboxes of the settings view?

Here is the idea:

The user is presented with a settings view where they will choose a category or categories:

[The "Settings" view with category checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B71UT.png)

Then, when the quiz mode begins, they will be presented only with the questions found in the "category/s" they have selected:

[Quiz mode with selected category/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJxPA.png)

Comment: Your questions is a bit broad, but start with thinking about how you will store the data.  I would suggest a dictionary using the category as the key and an array of questions for that category as the value associated with the key. Then you can retrieve the categories by getting all,of e keys from the dictionary and the appropriate questions by getting the array associate with the relevant key

Comment: have u tried some code for that. pop up some code. it u stuck then ask for help

Comment: its simple.save ur data accordingly in plist.e.save each category as array with key ur category name.

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough details. Yes I am already done with the questions being stored with keys and arrays in a Plist. My only problem is that I need to display only the questions which contain a certain "Category" string... For instance, only the arrays with the category "Animals" are to be displayed...

Comment: I have edited my question. Pls check

Answer (score 0):

Create your plist with following structure.[image]

For `displaying` your categories as checkboxes,extract all keys from plist dictionary.

```
NSArray *categories = [plistDictionary allKeys];
```

For selecting particular questions under a category, pass your selected checkbox category as key to retrieve particular array from plist dictionary.

```
NSarray *questions = [plistDictionary valueForKey:@"YourSelectedCategory"];
```

Comment: Hi, can you do that on swift? I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: thats simple, just convert it.Please refer the NSDictionary and NSArray classes.

Answer (score 0):

Get plist data like below..

I have plist file as structure you given in your question..

Suppose you choose cat1 then you will get data which have category = "cat1".

[image]

```
  var myDict: NSDictionary?
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
    //var categoryArray = NSMutableArray()
    if let dict = myDict {
        // Use your dict here
        let questionArray =  (dict.objectForKey("Questions") as! NSArray)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF.Category == %@)","cat1")
        let filterArray = (questionArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate) as NSArray)
    //Here i am filter out data for category "cat1"
    //It will show all filter data which contain category="cat1"    
        print("\(filterArray)")

    }
```

Comment: Plist will be an dictionary.And NSArray doesn't have a valueForKeyPath method.

Comment: I have implemented code in Xcode as per your requirement.it will solve your problem..

Comment: I have put an effort for same..can you just put little effort by accepting or upvoting my answer?